# How set List in Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, hateoas

I'm developing my first application that uses *Spring Rest*, I have a class `Veiculo.class`, `Agencia.class` and `Contato.class`. When I created a `Veiculo` object, that needs a List which contents `Agencia` and `Spring` generates correctly the hypermedia to my:

Entity

```
@Document
public class Veiculo{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String nome;
    private String tipo;
    @DBRef
    List<Contato> contatos;

    @DBRef
    List<Agencia> agencias;

//getters and setters

}
```

Curl

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6
{
  "nome" : "veiculo",
  "tipo" : "tipo",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6"
    },
    "contatos" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/contatos"
    },
    "agencias" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/agencias"
    }
  }
}
```

I need set the List of Agencia in the path */55a512a7ccf2bc55501419dc/agencias* (is a Veiculo attribute) but how I do this? **I didn't find any example** of what I need

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/agencias
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/agencias"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "agencias" : [ ]
  }
}
```

When I do a `POST` this happens

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"agencias": [{"nome": "um"}]}' http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/agencias
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 14:31:14 GMT

daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/agencias
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/agencias"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "agencias" : [ ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `POST` to  `/55a512a7ccf2bc55501419dc/agencias` with the list of `agencias` in the body.

Comment: I tried to send the array but when I give a GET returns nothing